# Organic Groups group_access missing from add

Tags: entities, organic-groups, 7, nodes

I'm working on a customized commons site. I'm not able to create content for a custom group (e.g.: MyGroup) with the group_access field set to required because it doesn't render in the add content mode, but I still get the message saying "Group visibility field is required". The field doesn't even render, so you can't set the value, but of course, the required property is triggering validation.

Oddly, if I create content and select Group, I can complete the creation of the content, despite the fact that the group_access doesn't even render for that content type either. It makes me wonder what' been customized, but none of the custom modules mention this field.

Note: The group_access field has been added, so it's in the content type's manage fields interface, it's just not showing up in the add new node of that "group/content type".

Any ideas as to what's got to be changed to fix this would be greatly appreciated.
Thx!

Comment: Have you gone through all this in vanilla Drupal installation so that you have a reference point of everything working as it should?

Comment: Kari, no, but I've used commons in the past and seen that this works, so it doesn't seem practical to do that again. Thanks.

Comment: One more thing I just noticed, my previous experience was with an older version of commons, so I don't know if there would be a major difference, but I read the .info file in the commons_group directory and saw that it's version 7.x-3.0, and the latest commons project release looks like 3.9, so I wonder if there's an issue with that. I can try this, but am going to have to create a second installation to avoid killing what is an otherwise working site. If anyone has feedback on that discovery, I'm all ears. Thx.

Comment: I'm noticing that many (if not most) of the "commons_" modules I have installed on this installation have a message on their project site reading "This project has been merged into the main Drupal Commons repository...". My first thought is that this must be the cause of my issues, but then I realize that this should be happening to others as well, and I haven't found other posts related to this.

Advice requested and appreciated.

Comment: I have installed a fresh copy of the commons distro, version 3.9, and still have this same issue. the group_access (group visibility) field is missing from the source altogether. Any thoughts on why?

Comment: Spoke with an Acquia rep helped me resolve the issue of not being able to keep private content from displaying publicly. However, I learned that, in this version of Commons, you can not create more than one group content type, called 'group'. Creating another content type as a group causes various issues. Additionally, the group_access field no longer displays, even tho it's added to the group content type. Bazaar. Finally, the rep recommended that I try a plain vanilla Drupal install, add OG, and try again. Sad that I have to go thru this. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: That was unexpected. Great that you found that out.